# No module named <packname> - PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I have searched for the problem on the site, but could not find the case or a similar one. This one I checked also as the best matching
[tihs one](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203368550--No-module-named-xx-when-editing-file-but-python-executes-it-fine).

I am using the system interpreter, **Python (v3.7.0)**, and I can access all the packages in the python IDE no import error or something like that. In fact, when I use PyCharm and try to use import statement in the script, it shows 'No module named ', and when I run the script on PyCharm or from a different source it works with no error. In other words, I have a problem only in IDE, and since PyCharm IDE shows an error that there is no module when I am scripting, I cannot use the PyCharm IDE things associated with that module such as auto-complete. Yet, when I run the script from any shell or IDE they all successfully run the codes.

I don't figure out what is wrong, but I will provided some images below.
I have been using PyCharm for the projects, lately I've probably done sth wrong, but not sure so that PyCharms throws an error in **IDE while scripting**. The thing is while scripting when I use import statement PyCharm does not recognize the module which is already installed.

I don't figure out what is wrong, but I will provided some images below.

1st
[image: https://i.imgur.com/RIraqzo.png]

2nd
[image]

3rd
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked the **Project Interpreter**? If the interpreter you are using is different from IDLE, this might happens. Go to **Preference** -> **Project Interpreter**, and check the interpreter you are using it now. You can also check the packages that are currently being installed right away.

Comment: In Project Interpreter, the system interpreter Python (3.7.0) showing the correct path and libs. I can see all of the packages on Project Interpreter as well.